# "have not done" or "have not been doing"

Tags: progressive-aspect

I want to convey that I didn't speak English in the last two years and I'm not speaking English now.

> I haven't spoken English for two years.
>
> I haven't been speaking English for two years.

In this case, which is proper?

Comment: @AlanCarmack I wonder if their negative form work the same.

Comment: I removed your second question, as it has no relevance to the first. Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences imply that now you are speaking English,

> I haven't spoken English for two years, (but I am now).
>
> I haven't been speaking English for two years, (but I am now).

What you should say is;

> I haven't spoken English for two years, *I still don't.*

or

> I haven't been speaking English for two years, *I still don't*

Comment: Does the sentence "I have been speaking English for 2 years" imply that I still speak English now?

Comment: yes it does. **

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/englishs-imperfect-tense-and-its-imperfection   This explains why it implies that much better than I can @MingWang

Comment: I don't understand why both "haven't been speaking English" and "have been speaking English" imply that I'm speaking English now.

Comment: No, 'haven't been speaking English,' implies that you still DO NOT, but 'have been speaking English,' implies that you still DO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why you wrote "Both sentences imply that now you are speaking English"? Is that a typo?